# Android studio preview window for xml files

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Is the preview of xml file is removed from Android studio 3.0.1 latest version if no then how to enable it

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is always available and normally it is active by default. If it does not show up in your home it is certainly a problem to update the libraries of Sdk

Answer (score 1):

The preview pane is still included in Android Studio 3.0.1.

Show the preview view by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and typing preview.

[image: search pane]

Comment: Which min sdk required to enable preview window of layout . I have installed 8.0 completed with API 27 But still not getting prebiew option.